# Libgdx AssetManager not loading resources on resume

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I am using Libgdx assetmanager to load UI assets. It works perfectly fine until I restart the application(Android).
Here is what happens:

1. I start my game: It runs fine
2. I close the application using `Gdx.app.exit()` (No errors)
3. Now when I press on the app icon to open it: crashed!

Error: `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: data/GUI/packed/gui.atlas`

I tried `finishloading()` No luck!
I tried using `finishloadingasset("data/GUI/packed/gui.atlas")` this blocks forever!
Added `assetmanager.dispose()` also clear before exit. No luck!

After it is crashed, if i try to open it again it works just fine!

Please advice!
Thanks

Comment: Show some code, and the actual stack trace of the crash.

Comment: Let me guess...you have a static reference to your AssetManager, or a class that references it. This will cause problems in Android, because closing an Activity in Android does not automatically clear your static references.

Comment: Yes you are right! I have declared assetmanager as static! Let me try making it non static and get back. Thanks

Comment: Tenfour04, You were absolutely right.. Could you please rewrite the comment as the answer so that I can mark it as the answer for the benefit of other people like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing an Activity in Android does not automatically clear your static references. Do not hold any static references to any OpenGL-related objects such as AssetManagers, Textures, ShaderPrograms, SpriteBatches, etc., or you risk Android reopening your game without knowing how (or that it needs) to reload them.

There might be ways around this by clearing your static references in your Activity's `onCreate` method, but it's safer/easier to avoid static references altogether.